# Divisor on cubic curve $y^2z=x^3-xz^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be the nonsingular cubic curve $y^2z=x^3-xz^2$. Let $P_0=(0,1,0)$. Then the line bundle associated to $3P_0$ is $O_X(1)$. I already know that $3P_0$ is produced by cut the curve with $z=0$. But why this is enough to get it is $O_X(1)$.

Comment: In general you would get that the associated line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ is isomorphic to $\varphi^*(O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$ where $\varphi: X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is defined by the global sections of $\mathscr{L}$. But in this case the divisor $3 P_0$ was used to embed $X$ into projective space in the first place (hence the nice Weierstrass equation), so $\varphi$ is just the inclusion map $\iota: X \to \mathbb{P}^2$. I think this means that $\mathscr{L} \cong \iota^*(O_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)) \cong O_X(1)$.

Comment: @André3000 Thank you for your solution. However, I am not quite familiar with the Weierstrass equation. I try to argue it as every divisor in $\mathbb{P}^2$ restricts to a divisor on $X$, and $z=0$ is a divisor associated to $O_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ (as we have an obvious embedding of this curve to projective space). Thus it should also give a divisor corresponding to $O_X(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. One nice thing about the divisor and line bundle correspondence is that the divisor is the divisor of any rational section. Sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ pullback to sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$, and the associated divisor of a pulled-back section gives you a divisor $D$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(D)=\mathcal{O}_X(1)$. You did this computation and everything works!